# Using a recursive function to capitalize each word in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

For an algorithm challenge on Udemy the question was to write a recursive function that capitalizes every word in an array. They provided a solution that I do not understand. Can someone explain to me step by step what happens, and why this code works?

```
function capitalizeWords (array) {
  if (array.length === 1) {
    return [array[0].toUpperCase()];
  }
  let res = capitalizeWords(array.slice(0, -1));
  res.push(array.slice(array.length-1)[0].toUpperCase());
  return res;
 
}
```

Comment: can you not just track it line by line? which line is too complicated?

Comment: The let res = line I don't get. Does it run past this line on first iteration? Or does it halt untill every call to capitalizeWords gets resolved? And also, how does res bedome an array?

Comment: `res` becomes an array because the base case returns an array, and all the other cases push onto the array returned by the previous case.

Comment: @PeterStaal just follow the flow like `capitalizeWords` is a normal function, I think you would know the answer if it would call function with another name. Also this function doesn't work for empty array input

Answer (score 1):

The logic is straightforward, end common to many recursive algorithms.

When asked to capitalize all words in a (non-empty) array, there are two possible cases:

1. The array only has one element. This is simple: you just capitalize that element, and return the result in an array. Returning this as an array ensures that `res` will be an array in the caller.
2. The array has more than one element. In this case, you extract a slice of the array excluding one element (the code you posted excludes the last element). You call the function recursively on this slice. Then you capitalize the remaining word, add that to the array that was returned by the recursive call, and return this as the result.

Each recursive call operates on smaller slices of the array until it reaches case 1. After each call returns, the results are combined and eventually produce the results for the entire array.

Taking it step by step with an the call `capitalizeWords(["ab", "cd", "ef"])`:

In the first call, `array.length == 3` so the first `if` is skipped. It then does `let res = capitalizeWords(["ab", "cd"])`

In the second call, `array.length == 2`, so the first if is skipped. It then does `let res = capitalizeWords(["ab"])`.

In the third call, `array.length == 1`, so the `if` condition succeeds. It executes `return [array[0].toUpperCase()];` which returns the array `["AB"]`.

We return to the second call, so now `res == ["AB"]`. `array.slice(array.length-1)[0] == "cd"`, we capitalize that to get `"CD"`, and push that onto `res`, so now `res == ["AB", "CD"]`. This is returned with `return res`.

We return to the first call, so now `res == ["AB", "CD"]`. `array.slice(array.length-1)[0] == "ef"`, we capitalize that to get `"EF"`, and push that onto `res`, so now `res == ["AB", "CD", "EF"]`. This is returned with `return res`.

This is what the original caller receives as their result.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how this would work with an array of [a,b,c]? Just to make sure I fully understand?

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work :

```
function capitalize(arr=[]){
  
  const makeCapital = (str)=>{
   return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase()
  }
 
  if(arr.length > 0){
 
    return [makeCapital(arr.shift())].concat(capitalize(arr))
  }
  return arr
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short and sweet answer that should be easy to understand:

```
var capitalizeFirst = function(array) {
    if (array.length === 0) return [];
  
  let chars = array[0].split('');
  chars[0] = chars[0].toUpperCase();
  
  return [chars.join('')].concat(capitalizeFirst(array.slice(1)));
  
};
```